# Is there a well-defined way to describe the transformation of a line into a circle as the connecting of the ends of the line?

Tags: geometry

Consider the line $y=0$ and the circle $x^2+(y-2)^2 = 4$:

[image]

Intuitively, it is easy to imagine that one can take a subset of the graph of $y=0$ whose length is the same as the circumference of the circle, and imagine grabbing the ends and connecting them to create the graph of that circle.

I was wondering, is there a well-defined set of partial transformations (a set of lines) with no gaps describing this transformation? By this I mean that, if we could animate the above transformation of the line into the circle, there would be no sudden jumps in the animation (i.e., this set of partial transformations sort of behaves like an interval of the real numbers).

Here's a crude example of the elements of the set of partial transformations, with three elements of the set (there are infinitely many elements between these elements):

[image]

Comment: You want a way to describe what “way” each point on the line will go through until he reaches his final position?

Comment: @tau_knight right! I'm looking for a mathematical description of the fact of making the line into the circle, specifically, the "way" from the line to the circle, and I'd want this "way" to have no gaps in it

Comment: Keep in mind that there are multiple ways to do so, for example: all the dots can start “bending” all together, or another option, a dot will start bending only when the “previous” one finished (until then, this dot and all the ones ahead “behave” as a line)

Comment: @tau_knight noted! I added a crude paint sketch

Comment: I assume that throughout the transformation, the length of the curve must stay constant, i.e., it does neither stretch nor shrink?

Comment: @VTand that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: @shintuku: Each endpoint will trace an [involute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute) of the circle.

Comment: I think this will give you a mathematical solution: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cass/graphics/manual/pdf/ch8.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj-lfTev_f7AhUEz4UKHWbjADQQFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1jZhQivwcYUC6t2SNleaA2 . To make it short, you have to multiply the equation by the desired Jacobian of the transformation. Regarding how to do it smoothly for all the dots simultaneously, it's more of a programing question than a mathematical one. Good luck!

Comment: @tau_knight thanks for the resource!!